# Can I Reconfigure My Vent Pipe As Suggested In This Rendering?

Tags: plumbing, drain, drain-waste-vent

I'm moving a wall back a few feet, but when I opened up the wall, I found a pipe going horizontally about 16 inches from the floor, connected to my 3" drain pipe coming from the toilet upstairs, and I followed it in the basement and it's connected to the same pipe that the tub's p-trap is draining to.  I believe the purpose of this pipe is for venting?

I'm hoping that I can reroute that pipe in the way that I showed in the render video here:
[Rendering of my proposed rerouting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXbQY.jpg)

Basically I want to have it run under the floor instead of through that wall.

Is this realistic?

Edit: As requested, here are actual photos:
[Actual Photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNIfu.jpg)

Comment: Now that you have show us your impressive rendering skills, can you also take a picture

Comment: But, I live in the metaverse? Just kidding... Edited original post with photos.

Comment: Nice video, but a simple before/after pic pair would have been much easier. ;)

Comment: It only took me a few minutes in Fusion 360 (amazing what that software can do for the layman).  But I realize now that a picture is probably worth way more in these types of questions.  I'll be better next time :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that but some things not shown in your rendering:

1. The horizontal pipe should be a little larger than the fixture's trap.  Maybe the trap is 1-1/4", then maybe you can use 2" for the horizontal.
2. The entire horizontal run should be sloped, should run consistently downwards from the highest point near the main vent to the lowest point near the main drain, with no sagging.  If it's very long you may not have enough room under the floor to do that.  You won't want to waste a couple of inches of rise with a double elbow as you did in the rendering.
3. The new vent pipe should join the bigger riser with a Wye pointed downwards, not a Tee.

Is it realistic?  There are no joists in your rendering.  Running a vent pipe diagonally or in two perpendicular directions you'll have to figure out how to deal with joists.  You can't always drill 2 inch holes in joists.  It will be more realistic if the horizontal part of the toilet drain is in the basement and is several inches below the joists.

**Plan B**

If it turns out to be unrealistic another possible way to do it is to take advantage of the floor void in TWO floors -- above AND below.  Run horizontally, with appropriate slope, to the corner of the room, then run vertically through the ceiling to the next floor.  There you'll have a new, entire floor thickness in which to get across to the riser.  Sorry I can't render that.  If it's not clear I'll do a napkin drawing.  In other words, your replacement pipe should be in the floor above not the floor below, to double the space available for sloping the pipe.

**Logic**

Here I added labels a, b, c to your drawing.

I think it's obvious that from b to c has to be "downhill" so the water will drain.  What is less obvious is that from a to b has to be entirely downhill.  If it's not or if it sags or if you stick a U-shaped bend in to avoid an obstacle, then, when (not if) any water enters, it will remain there permanently and you won't have a vent.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I edited my original post with photos. Does your first solution still work with that?

Comment: The photo is not relevant to my answer.   I thought your rendering was pretty clear without the photo!  My "first solution" is your solution ... just with some caveats.   It will be very difficult for you to show me in photos whether all my caveats leave your solution realistic.  You have to try to dry-run the pipes with the needed slope and see if it all fits.

Comment: I added a new "logic" section at the end of the answer to help illustrate what you need to achieve.